# I need to write a Ansible Playbook for Ubuntu server

Tags: ansible

I need to  write an Ansible Playbook for ubuntu server

which will execute bellow tacks
1. Login to any Ubuntu Server
2. Enable Firewall
3. Drops all request by default
4. Open the following ports: 53, 1194/udp, 443/tcp, 80/tcp, 22/tcp

Can anyone help me with this assignment to provide me some useful resource

Answer (score -1):

I just began diving into Ansible myself. Here are a few videos and other resources I came across. The star ratings are my personal opinion of the resources. Keep in mind that a lot has changed in Ansible in the last 2-3 years.

- linda.com free trial
- [linuxacademy.com](https://linuxacademy.com/)
- YouTube: [Ansible - an absolute basic overview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfoAb50Br94) ★★★★
- YouTube: Ansible - A Beginner's Tutorial ★★★ parts [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icR-df2Olm8) [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRZA9ymZXn0) [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBiueVhDg1Q) [4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aeGDc7rCK_0) [5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Z-evEafMvY)
- YouTube: [What Is Ansible?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgQ3rHFTM4E) ★★
- YouTube: [Ansible Playbook Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCQpaTTTv98) ★★
- ansible.com: [Quick Start video](https://fast.wistia.net/embed/iframe/qrqfj371b6) ★★★★★
- YouTube: [Ansible Bootstrap Playbook](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7pw7z00CeU) ★★★★★
- YouTube: [Network Automation using Ansible and Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYEVjKvMKqU) (2015) ★★★
- [How to Use Ansible: A Reference Guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-cheat-sheet-guide)
- [10 Things you should start using in your Ansible Playbook](https://medium.com/@abhijeet.kamble619/10-things-you-should-start-using-in-your-ansible-playbook-808daff76b65)

I hope you enjoy learning about Ansible. I certainly have!

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions